# Infer type of props based on component passed also as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to infer correct types for props from an unknown component passed also as a prop?

In case of known component (that exists in current file) I can get props:

```
type ButtonProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>;
```

But if I want to create a generic component `Box` that accepts a component in `as` prop and the component's props in `props` prop. The component can add some default props, have some behavior, it doesn't matter. Basically its similar to higher-order components, but its dynamic.

```
import React from "react";

export interface BoxProps<TComponent> {
  as?: TComponent;
  props?: SomehowInfer<TComponent>; // is it possible?
}

export function Box({ as: Component, props }: BoxProps) {
  // Note: it doesn't have to be typed within the Box (I can pass anything, I can control it)
  return <Component className="box" title="This is Box!" {...props} />;
}

function MyButton(props: {onClick: () => void}) {
  return <button className="my-button" {...props} />;
}

// usage:

function Example() {
  // I want here the props to be typed based on what I pass to as. Without using typeof or explicitly passing the generic type. 
  return (
    <div>
      <Box
        as={MyButton}
        props={{
          onClick: () => {
            console.log("clicked");
          }
        }}
      >
        Click me.
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

requirements:

- must work without passing the generic type (is it possible?), because it would be used almost everywhere
- must work with user-defined components (`React.ComponentType<Props>`)
- would be great if it worked also with react html elements (a, button, link, ...they have different props), but not necessary

Comment: I am struggling to do something similar with forwardRef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the predefined react type `ComponentProps` to extract the prop types from a component type.

```
import React from "react";

export type BoxProps<TComponent extends React.ComponentType<any>> = {
  as: TComponent;
  props: React.ComponentProps<TComponent>;
}

export function Box<TComponent extends React.ComponentType<any>>({ as: Component, props }: BoxProps<TComponent>) {  
  return <div className="box" title="This is Box!">
    <Component  {...props} />;
  </div>
}

function MyButton(props: {onClick: () => void}) {
  return <button className="my-button" {...props} />;
}

// usage:

function Example() {
  // I want here the props to be typed based on what I pass to as. Without using typeof or explicitly passing the generic type. 
  return (
    <div>
      <Box
        as={MyButton}
        props={{ onClick: () => { } }}
      ></Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=43#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCqQA9JY4YBPMJOAIQloAUcwAzgB4AKgGFckAHZIp8OjFkATAYmIwAdBPAQZckayRCUU5gD4zcALxwA3lThwUAgFxxxk3bJgVKjsPyuauia2tLefBCComFecma+AL5UNPTQWACuUhjAupzcMZ568rSKUirBGFpF3gZsxqYWABS2TkGxxQA0cAFRqoluXLyBhTrFZgCUdo4OcEQwGVBScEJKwABucGgANs4CAHIoIEhW+ABG3PhMwDDbJ-giABbAqi-5tACE+GazjkId3kctg0IN6gkScAA9AlZkJIWt1j9KMk-HAqJgsjk8gBZZgcDIwGC6JpgoK2XRibbANAAazcTSmVks6wgwCUiSm9lR80WyyEZwJROWOz2h2OpxAzAAtALCborsDQYEIdCkilKJDIXAMgIUABzJAudUY7IwXLLACitCOYDuDLss01cAAknAAO4meCPJBEJjenqBJgQOBndgsNhKEPOJCRvJux4oeCusB7INtDRwADqN0eEAJ2oEwCkeqYhggmDg0DgdFt1Ju22YPT2RZLMH9BpkUGppbYGdmPKWcCavxWCKRjgnKyGI8nzistlx+LlUhRk8npPnrQpVNp9MZllaEMSq7XZjhQ3HE7hY9mEySQA)

Depending on you exact use case the solution might vary, but the basic idea is similar. You could for example turn the type around a little bit and take in the props as the type parameter for the `BoxProps`. That way you can constrain the component props to have some specific properties you can supply inside the `Box` component:

```
export type BoxProps<TProps extends {title: string}> = {
  as: React.ComponentType<TProps>;
} & {
  props: Omit<TProps, 'title'>;
}

export function Box<TProps extends {title: string}>({ as: Component, props }: BoxProps<TProps>) {  
  return <div className="box" title="This is Box!">
    <Component title="Title from box" {...props as TProps} />;
  </div>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#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-VgQPCn4KtltvKZRD6+jgnjotTk4T2clIA)

If you want to take in intrinsic tags, you can also add `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements` to the `TComponent` constraint:

```
export type BoxProps<TComponent extends React.ComponentType<any> | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = {
  as: TComponent;
  props: React.ComponentProps<TComponent>;
}

export function Box<TComponent extends React.ComponentType<any>| keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>({ as: Component, props }: BoxProps<TComponent>) {  
  return <div className="box" title="This is Box!">
    <Component  {...props} />;
  </div>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCqQA9JY4YBPMJOAIQloAUcwAzgB4AKgGFckAHZIp8OjFkATAYmIwAdBPAQZckayRCUU5gD44AHzgBrJMwiY4AKQDKADQ0BJOVGBSBYDQAUQAbJBBZGAELAF44AG8qODgUAQAuOHFJXSiKShSwfgy1dE1taSi+CEFRCty5M3yAXyoaemgsAFcpDGBdTm46nL15WkUpFVKMLRGogzZjUzNrOwcnN08fGD8AoLCIqJiACgTUkvrRgBo4IprVZsyuXmLhnVGzAEpElOS4IhgXSgUjgQiUwAAbnA0KE0gIAHIoSKxfAAI24+CYwBg4RRIgAFsBVETBrQAIT4Mx-FJCS5RFIJDRMu6CZpwAD0TT+QnZ4IhVMorQKcComB6fQGAFlmBwujAYLpjiySgldGJQkEbJljt9YhYIRBgEpmt8ksKAUCQUJUXKFSCYXDEcj8CBmABaG3y3SYxnM4pszktNqUdnsuBdAQoADmSHSwbFvRg-RBwVoSLA4R1iT+obgXjgAHcTPB8UgiExS7dikwIHBUewWGwlHW0khmwMC-iUPB82A4TXzho4AB1bH4iBy8OBKRRpiGRxwaBwOgZoLY0LMW5w-yzmCVmMyPxoOdsId-C3AuDHamgvkClIP0HPG+PtKxBLS2VeqRCx+P5XvmcaoamgWpXrqFhnGyzS-n+Zg8s894Pjyd5-J8QbUJQCYSimabgOEABMWZmikub5kWchwKW5Z7uwyoDvWJ5ti2AjMR2XY9luAiqAqg4jmOE7wBGO5MQuS4riB66bn23EibRcAHmWQRMWe5pIICl7XsKNKodpyHPnpr4CCifL4C+D4AQkCQweZ8HsohN4oZCSHoVQzRAA)